What exactly is voltage? What does it have to do with work?
I am a student and recently learned about electricity. I was reading about voltage. I see that the definition is the work done/charge. I think the work refers to the work done by the electrons as they flow due to the voltage (correct me if I am wrong). Since work done is considered, shouldn't the displacement also influence the voltage? Additionally I am unable to grasp the exact meaning of voltage. What exactly is it? How is work done related? Why is it related to work? What is the force acting here (I think electrostatic force). Why is the work done divided by charge?
I'm basically trying to understand how work is related to voltage, the displacement part of it and why it is divided by charge. I also asked for what voltage exactly means with respect to this work and what voltage is.

This question is similar to: What is voltage?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I have edited the question

Are you asking about displacement here because force–displacement work involves displacement? For electrical work, the analogous “generalized displacement” can be the amount of charge. Put another way, force–displacement is just one type of work, distinct from electrical work.

Oh, that's exactly what I wanted. Thank you
